# Java JUnit Eclipse error: Type mismatch cannot convert from void to double

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Good evening everyone,

I am a beginner in Java and I've done some research for what should be an extremely simple testing in JUnit of a method in Java. The entire class looks like this:

```
package calculator;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator 
{

private double accumulator;

// Default Constructor
public Calculator() 
{ 

}

// Parameterized Constructor
public Calculator(double initialValue) 
{ 
    accumulator = initialValue; 
}

// Other Methods
public void add(double number) 
{ 
    accumulator += number; 
}

public void subtract(double number) 
{ 
    accumulator -= number; 
}

public void multiply(double number) 
{ 
    accumulator *= number; 
}

public void divide(double number) 
{ 
    accumulator /= number; 
}

public void sqrt() 
{ 
    accumulator = Math.sqrt(accumulator);
}

public void setAccumlator(double accumulator)
{ 
    this.accumulator = accumulator;
}

public double getAccumulator() 
{ 
    return accumulator; 
}

@Override
public String toString() 
{ 
    return "Result:" + accumulator; 
}
}
```

I want to test for the method:

```
public void add(double number) 
{ 
    accumulator += number; 
}
```

So this is what I did:

```
package calculator;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class testAdd 
{

@Test
public void add(double number) 
{
    Calculator test = new Calculator(10.0);
    number = test.add(5.0);
    assertEquals(15.0, test);
}
}
```

The line of code:

```
number = test.add(5.0);
```

gives me the following error: Type mismatch. Cannot convert from void to double.

What should I do different? I've spent countless hours trying to figure it out but no luck so far...

Regards,

Pill Beans

Answer (score 1):

Return type of function `add` is void in class definition. Either change it to `double` and return a value.

Or just change `number = test.add(5.0);` to `test.add(5.0);` and then you could get value of `accumulator` from `test` object.

Answer (score 1):

Your "add" method returns void so you can't cast this to a double value. Your JUnit test should look like:

```
@Test
public void add(){
    Calculator test = new Calculator(10.0);
    test.add(5.0);
    assertEquals(15.0, test.getAccumulator());
}
```

Also, you don't need to pass a value to the test method.

Comment: Thank you kryger. I changed my code to the above which makes absolute sense and it does remove the error, but strangely it still fails the test. It should pass. Maybe it is because it reports the warning : "The method assertEquals(double, double) from the type Assert is deprecated.

Comment: Use `assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta);` instead, where delta is 0. See http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double,%20double%29 for more information

Comment: It worked! you guys are great! ... Thanks Tobias Horst for sharing the new version of     assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta);    and thank you all again for contributing to the final result